# How to append chars except empty and comment-out lines via VIM?

Tags: vim, vi

For example,

```
#LINE0
LINE1
LINE2

LINE3
```

append DEBUG =>

```
#LINE0
LINE1 DEBUG
LINE2 DEBUG

LINE3 DEBUG
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `:global` command:

```
:%g!/\v^%(\s*\#|$)/ s/$/ DEBUG/
```

See `:help :global` for details.

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/\(.\+\)/\1 DEBUG/
```

In all lines, replace the string of at least one character with that string followed by `DEBUG`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Just update on exception of comment-out lines.

Answer (score 0):

Using global command makes it easier:

```
:g/./normal A DEBUG
```

Explanation:

```
: ................ command
g ................ global
/ ................ start search
. ................ any char
/ ................ end of search
normal ........... do the global command in normal mode
A ................ start appending mode (insert)
<space>DEBUG ..... what you need :)
```